# Will any linear combination of degree 3 b-splines be C2 continuous?

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity, spline

Question is as in title. I have read that natural cubic splines are always C2 continuous, but am unsure whether all cubic splines are.

Answer (score 2):

Not all degree 3 B-splines are $C^2$ continuous. They could be $C^1$ or even $C^0$ depending on the knot vector (or more specifically the knot multiplicities).

Comment: Thanks fang. This is probably is a stupid question, but is a linear combination of $C^2$ continuous b-splines (i.e., a spline) $C^2$ continuous?

Comment: @Jack, yes to your question.